# A single login page for multiple authentication types (including Azure AD) in .NET Core MVC

Tags: authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a **.NET Core 2.2 MVC** web-application. And I've added two authentication types/providers there:

1. Login/password with local users database (custom thing, without [.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie))
2. Azure AD

My goal is to have a login page at `/account/login` where users can choose between these two authentications and log-in with either of those. So every time an unauthenticated user would open any page (from a controller with `[Authorize]` attrubite), he would get redirected to `/account/login` page, which has a login/password web-form with its own submit button, and additionally a `Office 365 login` link/button.

Just to make it clear - I don't want a custom Microsoft sign-in / Azure AD page. I only want unauthenticated users to get my login page first, from where they can either log-in using my web-form or click on `Office 365 login` and get to Microsoft sign-in page.

Now, the authentication part is done and seems to work fine, I can log-in with either of authentications, but my plan with redirecting unauthenticated user to `/account/login` failed. What happens instead is that user is being redirected to Microsoft sign-in page right away. So it looks like Azure AD authentication has a higher priority somehow.

Here's my implementation.

`Startup.cs`:

```cs
// ...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // the presence of CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme doesn't seem to influence anything
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    // makes no difference either
    //services.AddAuthentication(
    //    options =>
    //    {
    //        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //    }
    //)
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, // and it also can be omitted here
            options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(45);
            })
        .AddAzureAD(options => _configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // as the default policy, it applies to all [Authorize] controllers
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        )
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser() // a simple policy that only requires a user to be authenticated
        .Build();
    });

    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    });

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        // it is my understanding that there is no need create a policy here
        // and perform "options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy))",
        // because the default policy is already added and controllers have explicit [Authorize] attribute
        // [...] well, actually I tried that too, but it didn't change anything

        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory
    )
{
    // ...

    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
    });
}
```

`AccountController.cs`:

```cs
[Authorize]
[Route("account")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // ...

    // that is where "Office 365 login" link leads
    [HttpGet("login-ad")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult LoginAD(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) { returnUrl = "/"; }
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl },
                AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                );
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    // that is where login/password web-form submits to
    [HttpPost("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _usersManager.SignIn(
                model.Login,
                model.Password
                );

            // ...

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }

    // ...
}
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```cs
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // ...

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, opening any page by an unauthenticated user results in immediate redirect to Microsoft sign-in page. And in order to get to `/account/login` (to have a chance to log-in using another authentication) users have to open that URL explicitly.

If I remove `AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` from default policy, then all unauthenticated requests will now get redirected to `/account/login` - exactly what I want - but naturally Azure AD authentication doesn't work anymore:

[image]

These redirects tell me that after successful authentication at Microsoft sign-in page it returns user back to `/account/login`, but user is still not authenticated on my website.

I can of course add `[AllowAnonymous]` to `Index` action of `HomeController` and return redirect to `/account/login` for unauthenticated users, but that obviously would only work for `/` route.

I have a feeling that I don't understand some things about `AddAuthentication()`, schemes and policies, thus apparently I did something wrong in `Startup.cs`. Can you please help me to understand what's wrong there? Or maybe there is some other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated answer

I decided to clone the example project mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample) in the quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp documentation and see if I could reproduce your error.

After cloning the project I added two NuGet packages.

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0

Then added the database context that extends IdentityContext.

- ApplicationDbContext.cs

In Startup.cs

- Registered Identity
- Registered the database context and provided connection string

In AppSettings.json

- Configured TenantID and ClientID

Ran the application.

At this point, the app launches and redirects me to Account/Login, where I choose Sign in via Microsoft account.

Now, I can obviously see there is something wrong. It wouldn't authenticate the user.

#### Turns out:

> The extension method `.AddAzureAd()` actually cannot be used in combination with other authentication methods. See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14455) issue on github.

But luckily the workaround is fairly simple. Just switch out `.AddAzureAd()` for `.AddOpenIdConnect()` and change your AppSettings' AzureAd section to:

```cs
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/v2.0/",
    "TenantId": "{tenantID}",
    "ClientId": "{clientID}",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

Now I can log in perfectly fine with AzureAD and local user accounts as well.

For your convenience, I uploaded the complete example project to my [GitHub page](https://github.com/mohdennis/aad-and-local-user-accounts).

Comment: Unfortunately, while it makes sense to me, your suggestion did not help - I got the same result as with removing `AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` from policy - user successfully authenticates on Microsoft sign-in page, but after redirecting back to `/` user is still not authenticated on my website and so it gets redirected again to login page: https://i.imgur.com/bIqmgiB.png. At the same time, authenticating with the second type of authentication (local database) works fine.

Comment: @retif I'm sorry to hear that my solution didn't work for you. I decided to clone the default AAD project from Microsoft and added just the bare minimum that you'd need to use local user accounts. And I can confirm that there aren't any problems in your code. It doesn't work with the bare minimum either. But I did manage to find a solution. So check out my answer in a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, I'd try specifying OpenIdConnect directly and not using the AddAzureAd helper.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Replacing `.AddAzureAD()` with `.AddOpenIdConnect()` did the job. One more thing I did is instead of putting `Authority` to config I composed it in `services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { .. })`. Thank you so much.